# What's an alternative to the "functional" package for the function composition operation?

Tags: python, functional-programming, python-3.6

In particular, I'm looking for a package w/ support for function composition.

Googling around, there's a lot of references to Collin Winter's functional and its compose() function. However documentation for that is gone: http://www.oakwinter.com/code/functional/

which doesn't lend me much confidence in its continued support.

A few references such as https://mathieularose.com/function-composition-in-python/ provide relatively simple hand-rolled implementation. However, unless it's absolutely necessary, I'd rather go with an existing library of there's one that the community is converging around rather than reimplementing such a basic operation.

Comment: It's like 4 lines. Why *not* just write it up yourself when you need it?

Comment: I can. But on projects I'd rather not replicate slightly different versions of compose, some written by me, others written by others, others using a library solution that i may not be aware of.

Comment: Since there doesn't seem to be anything around that does exactly what you want, and you seem to understand the problem, why not publish your own?  Write up a `compose`, maybe some additional functionality and stick it up on github.

Comment: Have you looked at the Python example in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_%28computer_science%29#First-class_composition) on Function Composition?

Comment: @martineau yes - issue here isn't knowing how to implement it - see above comment.

Comment: Write your own module and use it everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a big fan of [toolz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/toolz) and use it a lot in both personal projects and at work. It's actively maintained, well documented, and seems to be quite mature despite the 0.x version number.

It offers a [`compose`](http://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#functoolz) function that might be what you're looking for.

For example:

```
from toolz import compose

add_one = lambda x: x + 1
square = lambda x: x**2

# Add 1, then square
compose(square, add_one)(2)  # == 9
```